# timer doesn't generate interrupts... or what?

Tags: c++, timer, operating-system, interrupt

`#define TIMER_IVT_ENTRYNUM     0x1C`
or
`#define TIMER_IVT_ENTRYNUM     0x08`

```
    prevInt = getvect(TIMER_IVT_ENTRYNUM);
    setvect(TIMER_IVT_ENTRYNUM, currInt);
```

that is how I set my own interrupt handler which looks like this:

```
void interrupt Timer::currInt(...) {
    (*prevInt)(); //old timer routine
    cout << "TIMER occurence" << endl;

    lock();
    counter++;
    tick(); //empty body

    if ( (Kernel::getRunning() -> getTimeSlice() > 0) )
        if (counter >= Kernel::getRunning() -> getTimeSlice()) {
           unlock();
           dispatch();
           //dispatchInterrupt();
        };

    unlock();
};
```

anyway, timer interrupts don't occur on their own, at all... but if i call the int routine explicitly using `geninterrupt(TIMER_IVT_ENTRYNUM)` it works...

Like timer never generates interrupts itself... o.O 
I'm on Win XP 32bit, Borland C++ 3.1 (it's mandatory)

Comment: btw, to ensure that program runs over 55ms I load it with couple of millions of operations on volatile variables, because I'm not sure if `sleep(seconds)` is independent from timer... I suppose it is, but even then, there is no evidence of interrupt execution...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to apply some DOS stuff in Win XP? The last OS where it could work was Win98. Starting from WinNT, you can have direct access to hardware resources only in the kernel mode, writing kernel mode drivers.

In your case, try to find some user-mode equivalent for a timer interrupt handling (like Multimedia timers, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743609(v=vs.85).aspx), or start writing Windows drivers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/default.aspx

Regarding Borland C++ 3.1... I really have nothing to say :(

Comment: yeah, I know all that... but it's my "operating systems" assignment, I gotta do it that way... 
And I checked with colleagues, they all have pretty much the same code to initialize timer, and very similar in handler... :/

Comment: Old comment I know, but there is no reason why this shouldn't work on XP. Yes, XP doesn't allow direct HW access like 9x did, but, to maintain compatibility with DOS/Win9x/Win3x software, it provides emulated hardware that it _does_ allow old applications to access.